# Show the Content of input when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using  tag to view the individual content of each seven inputs. Everything is working well except that content only appears if I click on active inputs which I want to show as soon as the page loads.

For now when I load page, if it is Friday Today, it would highlight the fri input but won't show the content inside

it is friday

and only appears when it is re-clicked. So any help from anyone to show the content of

also when page loads.

Any help would be really appreciated.

here is the work

```
https://jsfiddle.net/BlueYeti/tcqjaetj/1/
```

and snippet file is

```js
$('form').on('click', function() {
 
  var day     = $("input[name='tabs']:checked").val(),
   whatDay = $('.day');
 
  whatDay.each(function(i) {
   $(whatDay[i]).removeClass('active');
    
    if ( $(whatDay[i]).hasClass(day)) {
    $(whatDay[i]).addClass('active');
     $('.set-day span').text($(this).find('p').text());
    }
  });
});


    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tabinator input[name=tabs]') // get all tabs
    .eq(new Date().getDay()) // select the current tab
    .prop('checked', true); // check it
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 2px;
  background: #E5E4E2;
}

.tabinator {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tabinator input {
  display: none;
}

.tabinator label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0.6%;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  font-family: courier;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.tabinator label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tabinator label:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}

#content1,
#content2,
#content3,
#content4,
#content5,
#content6,
#content7 {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3,
#tab4:checked~#content4, 
#tab5:checked~#content5,
#tab6:checked~#content6,
#tab7:checked~#content7 {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}


table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-indent: 0px; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border=0.5;   
 
}

table th {
   text-align: center;
    background-color:   #228B22; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 170%;
    border-color : black; 
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-style: solid;
   ; 
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
             0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
             0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);   
   

    
    
  }
    
 table td {
    
    padding-left: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 110%;

    border-color : black; 
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-family:  courier;
    color: blue;

text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
    
}



tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="tabinator">
  <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" value='sun' / checked>
    <label for="tab1">SUN</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs" value='mon' />
    <label for="tab2">MON</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab3" name="tabs" value='tue' />
    <label for="tab3">TUE</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab4" name="tabs" value='wed' />
    <label for="tab4">WED</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab5" name="tabs" value='thu' />
    <label for="tab5">THU</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab6" name="tabs" value='fri' />
    <label for="tab6">FRI</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab7" name="tabs" value='sat' />
    <label for="tab7">SAT</label>
</form>

<h1 class='set-day'><span></span> </h1>

<div id="content1">
<p > This is Sunday</p>
  </div>

  <div id="content2" class='day mon'>
    <p> This is Monday</p>
  </div>

  <div id="content3" class='day tue'>
    <p> This is Tuesday</p>
  </div>

  <div id="content4" class='day wed'>
    <p> This is Wednesday</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content5" class='day thu'>
    <p> This is Thursday</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content6" class='day fri'\>
    <p> This is Friday</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content7" class='day sat' >
    <p> This is Saturday</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should mark the correct answer as accepted/correct/answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Show the content on the load as you already did on the click. Here is code

```js
$('form').on('click', function() {
//moved the code into function called ShowDayContent to prevent duplication
 ShowDayContent();
});

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tabinator input[name=tabs]') // get all tabs
    .eq(new Date().getDay()) // select the current tab
    .prop('checked', true); // check it
    //calling the function here too
    ShowDayContent();
});
  //The code is just copied and pasted. No edits, just to avoid duplication.
  function ShowDayContent() {
     var day     = $("input[name='tabs']:checked").val(),
   whatDay = $('.day');
 
  whatDay.each(function(i) {
   $(whatDay[i]).removeClass('active');
    
    if ( $(whatDay[i]).hasClass(day)) {
    $(whatDay[i]).addClass('active');
     $('.set-day span').text($(this).find('p').text());
    }
  });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 2px;
  background: #E5E4E2;
}

.tabinator {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tabinator input {
  display: none;
}

.tabinator label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0.6%;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  font-family: courier;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.tabinator label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tabinator label:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}

#content1,
#content2,
#content3,
#content4,
#content5,
#content6,
#content7 {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3,
#tab4:checked~#content4, 
#tab5:checked~#content5,
#tab6:checked~#content6,
#tab7:checked~#content7 {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}


table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-indent: 0px; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border=0.5;   
 
}

table th {
   text-align: center;
    background-color:   #228B22; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 170%;
    border-color : black; 
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-style: solid;
   ; 
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
             0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
             0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);   
   

    
    
  }
    
 table td {
    
    padding-left: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 110%;

    border-color : black; 
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-family:  courier;
    color: blue;

text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
    
}



tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="tabinator">
  <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" value='sun' / checked>
    <label for="tab1">SUN</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs" value='mon' />
    <label for="tab2">MON</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab3" name="tabs" value='tue' />
    <label for="tab3">TUE</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab4" name="tabs" value='wed' />
    <label for="tab4">WED</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab5" name="tabs" value='thu' />
    <label for="tab5">THU</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab6" name="tabs" value='fri' />
    <label for="tab6">FRI</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab7" name="tabs" value='sat' />
    <label for="tab7">SAT</label>
</form>

<h1 class='set-day'><span></span> </h1>

<div id="content1">
<p > This is Sunday</p>
  </div>

  <div id="content2" class='day mon'>
    <p> This is Monday</p>
  </div>

  <div id="content3" class='day tue'>
    <p> This is Tuesday</p>
  </div>

  <div id="content4" class='day wed'>
    <p> This is Wednesday</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content5" class='day thu'>
    <p> This is Thursday</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content6" class='day fri'\>
    <p> This is Friday</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content7" class='day sat' >
    <p> This is Saturday</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well It is all what I wanted.Thank you all for being great Help.

Comment: Glade it helped. Feel free to select the answer as "accepted" if it's been satisfying answer to your question/problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are several improvements that can be made to your code:

1. Don't listen to the `click` event bubbling to the form. Instead, you can simply listen to the `change` event on the input elements. Clicking on the labels will toggle their check/uncheck states, which will fire the `change` event.
2. Remove the `.active` class outside the loop
3. When looping through the `whatDay` collection, you can simply use `$(this)` instead of the more verbose `$(whatDay[i])`
4. Finally, when the page is loaded, you can simply trigger the `change` event programatically, i.e. `.trigger('change')`, for the logic to run the first time without any user interaction.

Some additional, less relevant changes I have made:

- Added `class="day sun"` to the sunday content block
- Fixed a extraneous `/` in one of the input element

Without further ado, here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
$('form input[name="tabs"]').on('change', function() {

  var day = $(this).val(),
      whatDay = $('.day');

  // Remove class on all days
  whatDay.removeClass('active');

  // Show the correct day
  whatDay.each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass(day)) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.set-day span').text($(this).find('p').text());
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabinator input[name=tabs]')  // get all tabs
    .eq(new Date().getDay())        // select the current tab
    .prop('checked', true)          // check it
    .trigger('change');             // Trigger change
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 2px;
  background: #E5E4E2;
}

.tabinator {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tabinator input {
  display: none;
}

.tabinator label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0.6%;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  font-family: courier;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tabinator label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tabinator label:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}

#content1,
#content2,
#content3,
#content4,
#content5,
#content6,
#content7 {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3,
#tab4:checked~#content4,
#tab5:checked~#content5,
#tab6:checked~#content6,
#tab7:checked~#content7 {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-indent: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border=0.5;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #228B22;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 170%;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1.5px;
  border-style: solid;
  ;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

table td {
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 110%;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1.5px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-family: courier;
  color: blue;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="tabinator">
  <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" value='sun' />
  <label for="tab1">SUN</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs" value='mon' />
  <label for="tab2">MON</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab3" name="tabs" value='tue' />
  <label for="tab3">TUE</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab4" name="tabs" value='wed' />
  <label for="tab4">WED</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab5" name="tabs" value='thu' />
  <label for="tab5">THU</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab6" name="tabs" value='fri' />
  <label for="tab6">FRI</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab7" name="tabs" value='sat' />
  <label for="tab7">SAT</label>
</form>

<h1 class='set-day'><span></span> </h1>

<div id="content1" class='day sun'>
  <p> This is Sunday</p>
</div>

<div id="content2" class='day mon'>
  <p> This is Monday</p>
</div>

<div id="content3" class='day tue'>
  <p> This is Tuesday</p>
</div>

<div id="content4" class='day wed'>
  <p> This is Wednesday</p>
</div>

<div id="content5" class='day thu'>
  <p> This is Thursday</p>
</div>

<div id="content6" class='day fri'>
  <p> This is Friday</p>
</div>

<div id="content7" class='day sat'>
  <p> This is Saturday</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Props for going through the problems of existing script, Terry. I was considering it myself but thought it was too much, considering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Add .click() method when you pre-select the day like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabinator input[name=tabs]') // get all tabs
    .eq(new Date().getDay()) // select the current tab
    .prop('checked', true).click(); // check it
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcqjaetj/2/)